# IBus Pinying input works incorrectly if non-latin language installed

Tags: keyboard, language-support, ibus, input-language, pinyin

I have English, Ukrainian, Russian, Greek and Chinese Pinyin input languages (ordered as switched by keyboard shortcut) on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. If Pinying have been selected by keyboard shortcut the Chinese word "hao" appears as "ηαο" (in Greek letters). Swithing Pinyin after Russian/Ukrainian by mouse cause "рфщ" (Cyrillic). There is only one way to obtain right Chinese "好": switch to English (or other Latin) and after that directly switch to Pinyin. Is it possible to directly switch from any language to Pinyin? Is it a bug of the input language or something wrong in settings?

With best regards. Viktor.

Comment: Sounds as some kind of bug. If you install the `ibus-sunpinyin` package, and add SunPinyin, does it behave the same?

Comment: Used to happen to me if I switch via shortcut. Changing via mouse and script works OK . Do you want me to post the script ? I can rewrite it so it does the same as keyboard shortcut, cycles through those input methods. Also, Victor, I speak Russian so if you want , I can communicate with you in Russian too

Comment: Yes, I just checked, this still happens to me. I assume it is a bug, and probably could file bug report for this issue.  Let me know how you want my script to work. Do you just want it to switch to pinyin only, or cycle through the sources, or something else.

Comment: After installation of ibus-sunpinyin no new input methods appear. Also when I switch to Ukrainian or Russian and after that to Pinyin by mouse there is no Chinese. “Тш рфщ。“ instead of "你好。" There is only one correct character - point "。"

Comment: Dear Serg, please post the script. It is enough to switch to Pinyin.

Comment: Tested on UBUNTU 16.04. The same problem found.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I use M17N for Russian layout:

`ibus engine m17n:ru:kbd`

But its drawback is absence of Compose key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It only happens when you use a shortcut to switch to other languages to Chinese. My solution is putting an English keyboard in front of the Chinese keyboard in language and region settings in Ubuntu 18.04.